# Gradle creates TEST-junit.framework.TestSuite$1.xml when there is no test method

Tags: gradle, junit

I have an Test class that actually has no tests

```
public class TestNumbers3EmptyTest extends TestCase {

    public void TestNumbers3EmptyTest () {
    }

    public void noddInJunit3(){
                 //nothing needed here
    }
}
```

Gradle runs test but creates a file

```
build\test-results\test\TEST-junit.framework.TestSuite$1.xml
```

Content of the file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testsuite name="junit.framework.TestSuite$1" tests="1" skipped="0" failures="1" errors="0" timestamp="2020-12-17T08:17:55" hostname="INH-M123-W" time="0.004">
  <properties/>
  <testcase name="warning" classname="junit.framework.TestSuite$1" time="0.004">
    <failure message="junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: No tests found in org.sample.numberutils.TestNumbers3EmptyTest" type="junit.framework.AssertionFailedError">junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: No tests found in org.sample.numberutils.TestNumbers3EmptyTest
    at junit.framework.Assert.fail(Assert.java:57)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.fail(TestCase.java:223)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite$1.runTest(TestSuite.java:96)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:142)
    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:122)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:142)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:125)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:130)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:241)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:236)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:90)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:38)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:51)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:119)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:182)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:164)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:414)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
</failure>
  </testcase>
  <system-out><![CDATA[]]></system-out>
  <system-err><![CDATA[]]></system-err>
</testsuite>
```

HTML report from Gradle too uses the "incorrect" classname

Somehow the test name becomes "junit.framework.TestSuite$1". How can I make gradle write correct classname and use correct filename?

[image]

(We have a framework which runs the tests across many machines.  The filename and testclassname  are important information for the framework to do cleanup/retry etc)

Comment: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/15644